# Как подменить айпишник для приложения, которому нужен именно этот айпишник?

Tags: iptables, ip, linux, firewall, redirect

В общем задача такая, есть система **RHEL 6.4 Server** с парой сетевых интерфейсов объединенных в один посредством бондинга. У этой системы IP адрес: `10.7.7.1`. Далее на этой системе крутится приложуха которой нужен коннект к **MySQL** серверу `10.7.7.2` на `3306` порт. А на самом деле мускул крутится на `10.7.7.3`. Параметры коннекта захардкодены в приложуху поэтому их поменять нельзя. Слышал что можно через iptables сделать трансляцию адресов. Как сделать так чтобы когда приложуха обращалась на `10.7.7.2:3306` **iptables** это перехватывал и отправлял запрос на `10.7.7.3:3306`, и обратно получал ответ и скармливал его приложухе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -I  OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp  -d 10.7.7.2 --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.7.3:3306
```

Comment: и не забыть sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Comment: Не нужно! Это не форвардинг это nat.

Comment: Клёво! Работает. А как удалить это правило? На случай, если надо будет отменить...

Comment: Заместо -I пишите -D, а лучше одной командой man iptables.